# The Greedy Algorihm for Matroids works for maximisation and minimisation

Tags: matroids

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $(S,\mathcal{F})$ be a matroid and let $c:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a weight function on $S$. Find an algorithm that solves the following problem:
>
> MAXIMISATION PROBLEM FOR INDEPENDENCE SYSTEMS (MAX IS): Find an $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $c(F)$ is maximal.

From the lecture I know that the Greedy Algorithm associated with matroids can solve the similar problem:

> MINIMISATION PROBLEM FOR INDEPENDENCE SYSTEMS (MIN IS): Find a basis $B$ in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $c(B)$ is minimal.

So the question is how we can relate these two problems with one another. If we were considering minimum spanning trees I would simply change the signs of $c$ and use Kruskal's algorithm. However, it confuses me that MIN IS works over bases, but on the other hand I do realise that the $F$ from MAX IS have to be bases in case of positive weights...

Is there a way to make this connection here?

Comment: Consider $c' = -c$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I still do not get it. I don't think that a minimum weight basis $B$ for flipped weights corresponds to a maximum weight independent set $F \in \mathcal{F}$ regarding the original weights. (I mean we could drop all $s \in \mathcal{F}$ with negative weight and this would result in an independet set with more weight).

Comment: If you can find a minimum weight basis, you can also find a minimum weight independent set, by trying all possible sizes. The main observation is that truncation of a matroid, obtaining by retaining only independent sets of size at most $k$, is also a matroid (for an arbitrary value of $k$).